# Change local repo from master to main to push files to master repo at github

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push files to GitHub main repo as the master branch name is changed to main, but after
git init >
and git remote add >
as git initialized a master branch on my local,
how to push change and push to main check the error below.

```
$ git push origin/main main
error: src refspec main does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin/main'
```

Comment: `git push origin/main master` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several solution

Change default branch name

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

Create a main branch

```
git checkout -b main
```

Push your master branch to the origin main

```
git push origin/main master
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you change the upstream branch for your local `master` to `origin/main` with the [`--set-upstream-to`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---set-upstream-toltupstreamgt) option:

```sh
git switch master
git branch --unset-upstream
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/main
```

From that point on, you can just use the regular `git pull/git push` from your `master` branch and Git will interact with the `main` branch on the `origin` remote.

If you like to keep things in sync, you can also rename your local `master` branch to `main` with the [`--move`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---move) option:

```sh
git branch --move master main
```